# Сказуемое. Синтаксис

Tags: сказуемые, синтаксический-разбор

**Он рассказал, какая была в России умная интеллигенция.**

В придаточном предложении сказуемым будет сочетание "какая была" или "какая была умная"?

Comment: Да, вы правы: это определение.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сказуемое в вашем предложении "была умная". "Какая" в данном случае союзное слово.

Comment: Союзное слово "какая" выступает в роли определения?